# All AMP accordions expanded on reload

Tags: amp-html

Using multiple amp-accordion and nested-accordion in a sidebar. If one of the accordions is expanded when leaving the page and coming back, or reloading the page, ALL accordions are expanded on load. Is there anyways to stop this from happening? Is it expected behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. I had wrapped an amp-accordion around every section in my loop.

https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-accordion/